# I need help to fix sorting records in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, sorting

There is an table named 'Video'.
And I have to sorting like as following.

```
> Video 1 ActiveContest Boost = 1 Fill=80
> Video 2 ActiveContest Boost = 0 Fill=100
> Video 3 ActiveContest Boost = 0 Fill=20
> Video 4 NotInContest Boost = 0 Fill=0
> Video 5 PastContest Boost = 1 Fill=80
> Video 6 PastContest Boost = 1 Fill=100
```

At first we show all Videos which are in a active contest.
Inside this sorting of active Contest Videos we sort videos based on boost and fill. Boost means that videos will be shown on top of active contest.
If Video isn't boosted it depends on how much filled the video is.
After that we show videos random to users because it doesn't matter which position they have

Answer (score 0):

What is your data model ?

You can use $collections->sortBy()

[Laravel sortBy method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby)

```
$sorted = $collection->sortByAsc(function ($product, $key) {
    if ($product['contest'] != 'PastContest') {
        return $product['contest'];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
})->sortByDesc(function ($product, $key) {
    if ($product['contest'] != 'PastContest') {
        return $product['Boost'] . $product['Fill'];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

This should work on your case where contest can be sorted alphabetically, otherwise you can create a custom function.

Comment: But about past contests, I have to display randomly

Comment: I missed that point, I updated the answer, I didn't tested the code but the idea of my solution would be to ignore 'PastContest' with a custom function